# Counting problem, nickels and quarters.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A machine selects five coins at random from a purse containing ten quarters and four nickels.

1) Given that at least one nickel is selected, find the probability that there are at least two nickels selected.

I already solve (event A: the probability that there is at least one nickel selected) which is $0.8741$ and (event B:the probability that there are at least two nickels selected) which is $0.454$. The question asks about 
$$P(B \mid A) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$ 
The answer key said is $=0.519$. But I have no idea what I need to do to reach that number.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please write the answers you acquired, in the fraction, rather than its desimal round up form, and use [$LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) while posting something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in this specific case, $A\cap B = B$ since the event "Has at least one nickel" is a superset to the event "Has at least two nickels."  I.e. $A\supseteq B$, which is the same thing as saying $B\subseteq A$.

That is to say, whenever you have at least two nickels you also always have at least one nickel.

You say you calculated $P(A)\approxeq 0.8741$ and $P(B)\approxeq 0.454$ and you know that $P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$

Now, taking into account what I mentioned before, you have:

$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}=\frac{P(B)}{P(A)}\approxeq \frac{0.454}{0.8741}\approxeq 0.519$$